# Blasting gadgeteers object, Is it "Big boom" or "Boom Boom"?

Tags: deadlands-reloaded

#### Introduction:

As a mad scientist, I spend a lot of my time doing research following a strict protocol. I carry arround the result of my research. I had a little issue with my last craft, a little explosion... And my team start arguing about the "safety issue".

So I recreated the device and designed a test protocol where someone has to carry the device while I trigger it from a safe distance. But I struggle evaluating the result of the experience:

In twenty minutes, you can easily craft at home what non scientists call a blast bomb, infusing the blast power into a simple device.

How is the energy used when the device is triggered? As the blast can't used at once all the energie store.

#### Formulas:

```
Blastor: 10pp
Blast power points consumption : 2–6 
pp to damage conversion ratio : 2pp => 2d6, 
                                4pp => 3d6,
                                or 4pp => 2d6 + large blast, 
                                6pp => 3d6 + large blast
```

#### Test:

From the last words of the test subject, "haaaaaarg", and the remain of his body I can deduce that the blastor works, dealing 3d6 + large blast + 3d6.

But it was impossible to determine from the test subject's last words if the explosion was simultaneous or sequential.

This is relatively important for me, as I want to go further in my test.
If the explosions are sequential, I can find a test subject that will survive long enough to give me his impression after 2 blast at 3d6.  But the 6d6 large blast will require much tougher friends.

Comment: I wanted this question to have a fun tone as I lost 3 of my friend during this experience. Hidding such item in their backpack was a good for my security protocol. if it need to be more serious I will edit it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. How did you arrive at the conclusion that it *could* do 6d6 damage?

Comment: @kviiri, Item has 10 pp to use, 6 pp in one use 4pp in the other

Comment: So I've just posted an answer, but your comment has really confused me. Are you talking about casting the power twice in a row? If that's the case what is your actual question? I know you're going for a jokey style, but in this case it feels like its making your question virtually impossible to parse

Comment: I do not cast anything, my gadget have a power, and a amount of pp to use. My question is about the repartition of those pp.

Comment: Repartition? What do you mean?

Comment: Ohhhh, I think I get it. Give me a sec

Comment: Arg Damn french, The distribution of the pp in the skill blast. Does the item use Every point, in one time, only a part of the pp. I have hard time using the right word sorry for this.

Comment: Ready you last comment, I had the picture of a mad scietist saying: "Ohhh, wait a minute I have to test this!" followed by a Big boom, or 2 small one

Comment: I tried to clean up your grammar to make things clearer. Feel free to further revise.

Comment: Gah, I completely missed the word Gadgeteer in your question. Updating my answer to reflect this...

Comment: Please do adjust the question. Right now it's sacrificing clarity for fun, and doesn't make sense by simply reading it. The comments are required to understand it, and even then it requires a leap of interpretation. Fun is okay, but it has to come after clarity as a first priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly state in your question, depending on the amount of Power Points you spend, you have the following options each time you use the Blast Power:

- 2 PP - 2d6 damage in a Medium Burst Template (MBT)
- 4 PP - 3d6 damage in a Medium Burst Template or 2d6 in a Large Burst Template (LBT)
- 6 PP - 3d6 damage in a LBT

Note that whether it is a MBT or LBT only affects the area the damage affects, not the amount of damage caused.

Blast is also a ranged attack and not centred on the caster/user of the device. As a Mad Scientist, a common way of visualising the device is some kind of grenade launcher type thing.

Assuming you have 10 Power Points and use Blast twice in quick succession, you calculate and apply the damage from the two uses separately rather than combining the damage before applying it. It is worth noting that you will have to wait for your next turn before using your device for the second time, as you cannot activate it more than once in one round.

Example:

The first time you cast Blast with 6 Power Points for 3d6 damage in a LBT. You roll 13 damage, which you apply to the target and calculate whether they are Shaken and/or Wounded.

You then cast Blast a second time with 4 Power points for 3d6 in a MBT. This time you roll 6 damage, which you apply in the same way.

What you do NOT do is combine the two lots of damage and apply it all in one go. Applying the damage separately makes it much easier for a target to survive, as they are given the option to Soak each damaging attack individually rather than all the damage at once.

**The Gadgeteer Edge**

Assuming that you've used the Gadgeteer Edge to create the device, there is an extra limitation. As you note in your question, the device will have half the total Power Points of your normal devices. Also, when the device runs out of Power Points it ceases to be usable, and unlike a Mad Scientist's other powers, cannot be recharged. It is also commonly understood that Gadgeteer devices only last for the duration of a single session, even if they have Power Points left in them, although this is slightly more flexible depending on timings. It is intended to prevent you stocking up on masses of different devices. Gadgeteer is not intended to work like that - the devices are jury-rigged and temporary.

What this means in your scenario is that once it has used all 10 Power Points the device will stop working. It will not explode though, simply be unusable.

Comment: So the device survive the blast, and can be trigger up to 5 time. I guess Explosive Volleyball is going to be a thing in the west now!

Comment: @DragandDrop What do you mean 'the device survive the blast'?  Blast is a ranged attack and not centred on the user of the device.

Comment: Are you telling me that I did not create some tech grenade, and if my friend was the center of the explosion, it came from my lack of understanding of my power and my desire to watch them burn? I just switch my title from Mad Scientist to Bad Scientist.

Comment: @DragandDrop see my edit that talks specifically about the Gadgeteer Edge and how that works. Basically, devices created with it 'fall apart' after their Power Points run out, but they do not explode or damage the person using them.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me how to Mad Science. But can you stop saying that's I am the one choosing where it's going to explose. This is going to make my friend a little nervous, they already are suspicious.

Comment: @Drag The roleplaying in the question and comments is obscuring your question and requests for clarifying the answer. I appreciate that it's all in fun, but it's making our process here work more poorly than it should.